# Find how many grid cells contain x,y points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

So, I have written the code shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(-960,960,15)
y = np.random.randint(-540,540,15)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 11))
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', color='red', alpha=0.8)
img = plt.imread(scene_folder)
plt.imshow(img, extent = [-960, 960, -540, 540], aspect='auto')
plt.grid(color='white', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

This code generates this image:

[image]

So far, so good. What I want to achieve next is to check which grids contain points (red dots) and  get an image like this one (grids that contain red dots are now white):

[image]

Then, I want to get the number of grids that are white (or whatever color) and divide it by the total number of grids in that image. The picture above has 48 grids, 13 of which are white (13/48=27,1%).

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to list coordinates of all the pixels:

```
extent = [-960, 960, -540, 540]
p1, p2 = 8, 6
x1 = p1*(x-extent[0])//(extent[1]-extent[0])
y1 = p2*(y-extent[2])//(extent[3]-extent[2])
>>> np.transpose([x1, y1])
array([[4, 2],
       [6, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [7, 0],
       [6, 5],
       [1, 1],
       [5, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [4, 1],
       [3, 0],
       [7, 5],
       [3, 1],
       [1, 5],
       [4, 1],
       [0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

And then you can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find a number of different ones:

```
>>> len(np.unique(np.transpose([x1, y1]), axis=0))
14
```